# How can I activate UDP forwarding for USB communication between a PC and an Android app

Tags: android, redirect, networking, udp, adb

I have an *real* Android device connected to a computer via USB. I managed to activate **TCP** port forwarding with `adb forward tcp:<port> tcp:<port>` and successfully communicate with sockets but I don't know how to do the same for **UDP**.

**EDIT v1** : I launched my application on the emulator and typed `telnet localhost 5554` and `redir add udp:<port>:<port>` and it
worked, my function executeCMD is functionnal because when I try `ls`
it's working.

Some websites said to use `redir` like this `redir add udp:<port>:<port>` but when I do so I obtain an error :

```
usage:
    redir --lport=<n> --cport=<n> [options]
    redir --inetd --cport=<n>

    Options are:-
        --lport=<n>     port to listen on
        --laddr=IP      address of interface to listen on
        --cport=<n>     port to connect to
        --caddr=<host>      remote host to connect to
        --inetd     run from inetd
        --debug     output debugging info
        --timeout=<n>   set timeout to n seconds
        --syslog    log messages to syslog
        --name=<str>    tag syslog messages with 'str'
        --connect=<str> CONNECT string passed to proxy server
        --bind_addr=IP  bind() outgoing IP to given addr
        --ftp=<type>        redirect ftp connections
            where type is either port, pasv, both
        --transproxy    run in linux's transparent proxy mode
        --bufsize=<octets>  size of the buffer
        --max_bandwidth=<bit-per-sec>   limit the bandwidth
        --random_wait=<millisec>    wait before each packet
        --wait_in_out=<flag>    1 wait for in, 2 out, 3 in&out

    Version 2.2.1.
```

Then I thought this command should be launch on the Android device so I created this method :

```
 public String executeCMD(String cmd){
    StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
    try{
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int read;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        while ((read = reader.read(buffer)) > 0) output.append(buffer, 0, read);

        reader.close();
        process.waitFor();

    } catch(IOException e){ e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(InterruptedException e){ e.printStackTrace(); }

    return output.toString();
}
```

And when I called it like that :

```
executeCMD("redir add udp:" + UDP_PORT + ":" + UDP_PORT)
```

I get no output and the **UDP** server on the Android app can't communicate with the **UDP** client.

So I'm a bit lost... I'll continue searching but If you can help me; go ahead.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So finally, I did not find out how to enable UDP forwarding for USB communication but I did somethings else that works pretty well, but
**you have to enable USB tethering** *(from the computer ping the phone to see if it's properly enabled)*:

1. Create a TCP server on the phone and a TCP client on the desktop.
2. Execute `adb tcp:<port> tcp:<port>` on the desktop so it can communicate with the phone on `localhost` via TCP sockets.
3. Make the TCP server send the IP address *(on the USB tethering network)* of your phone to the TCP client.
4. Then you can close the TCP connection and with the address you can initiate an UDP connection with socket as you would in a normal situation.